# ThreadPoolExecutor and Spring Async

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Initially I was using regular java Multithreading using the 'implements' method. However @Autowired does not work when a class is created with `new` in Spring, so I am trying to change it to using Spring's`Async` method. This is what I have so far. How would I go about adding the threads to the ThreadPoolExecutor?

The class that should create the threads

```
@Component
public class ScheduledCountyScraper {

    @Autowired
    StateScrapeQueueRepository stateScrapeQueueRepository;

    @Autowired
    CountyScrapeRepository countyScrapeRepository;

    // @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 */3 * * *")
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void scrapeCountyLinks() {
        System.out.println("Scrape county links ran!");
        try {
            List<String> stateLinks = stateScrapeQueueRepository.getStatesLinks(website);
            ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

            //what to do here?

            executor.shutdown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("---------------------");
        }
    }

}
```

The Async class

```
@Component
@EnableAsync
public class CountyScraper {
    volatile private String stateLink;

    @Autowired
    StateScrapeQueueRepository stateScrapeQueueRepository;

    @Autowired
    CountyScrapeRepository countyScrapeRepository;

    public CountyScraper() {
    }

    public CountyScraper(String stateLink) {
        this.stateLink = stateLink;
    }

    @Async("countyScraper")
    public void run() {
        try {
            // other code

            stateScrapeQueueRepository.updateScrapeTimestamp(stateLink);
            countyScrapeRepository.insertCountyLinks(countyLinks, website);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default Spring uses a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` to execute async methods. This will by default spawn a new thread for every operation.

To define your own executor for use with async tasks, create a bean that implements the `TaskExecutor` interface or an `Executor` bean named `"taskExecutor"`.

If you'd like to have your own custom executor just for this component, you can `implement AsyncConfigurer` and provide your own executor service:

```
@Override
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    return MY_EXECUTOR;
}

@Override
public  AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    return MY_EXCEPTION_HANDLER;
}
```

Comment: I would do `implement AsyncConfigurer` on which class? the `ScheduledCountyScraper` or the `CountyScraper` class?

Comment: On `CountryScraper` since it has the `@Async` method.

Comment: I'm a little confused. How do we actually pass stateLink to `public CountyScraper(String stateLink) { ... } ` ?

Comment: I understand now. I have to Autowire the class

Comment: I did it a bit differently, can you take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56437029/spring-async-concurrenttaskexecutor-not-really-working-correctly