# Spring async ConcurrentTaskExecutor not really working correctly?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

It's my first time working with Async in Spring boot. Here is how my project is structured.

I have the following `ExecutorConfig` class

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ExecutorConfig {
    @Bean(name = "ConcurrentTaskExecutor")
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        return new ConcurrentTaskExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
    }
}
```

This following class which will be called with @Scheduled

```
@Component
public class RealtyTracCountyScraper {

    @Autowired
    StateScrapeQueueRepository stateScrapeQueueRepository;

    @Autowired
    CountyScrapeRepository countyScrapeRepository;

    @Autowired
    CountyScraper countyScraper;

    // @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 */3 * * *")
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void scrapeCountyLinks() {
        System.out.println("Scrape county links ran!");
        try {
            List<String> stateLinks = stateScrapeQueueRepository.getStatesLinks("");

            for (int i = 0; i < stateLinks.size(); i++) {
                countyScraper.run(stateLinks.get(i));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("---------------------");
        }
    }

}
```

and this class which gets called from the class above (This is the class that contains the multithreaded method)

```
@Component
public class CountyScraper implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    StateScrapeQueueRepository stateScrapeQueueRepository;

    @Autowired
    CountyScrapeRepository countyScrapeRepository;

    @Async("ConcurrentTaskExecutor")
    public void run(String stateLink) {
        System.out.println("New thread");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");

    }
}
```

Even though I have set 10 fixed threads in the `ExecutorConfig` class, it looks like only one thread works at a time. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just to make sure, have you enabled the Async? Where does the @EnableAsync  annotation appear?

Comment: I put that in the Main class

Comment: AsyncConfigurer is something that probably should be put on the @Configuration class its used for overriding the executor at the whole application level. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async here is a tutorial.... Maybe it will be useful...

Comment: I edited the `ExecutorConfig` class with the @Configuration and 
@EnableAsync annotations. But unfortunately still working as if it's one thread.The strange thing is, when I stop the program I get the `Application shutdown requested...` message, but the other thread keeps running until I press stop again.

Comment: For starters remove the `AsyncConfigurer` from your `CountyScraper`. That interface is for configuring the async stuff and currently you don't implement any of the methods and it will override/use a default executor. Your `@Scheduled` is commented and for `@Scheduled` to work you need `@EnableScheduling` as well. Currently you only act on an event (very early in the process) not on a scheule. Finally instead of `Executor` use `TaskExecutor` as a return type for your method to configure the `TaskExecutor` (or let that class implement `AsyncConfigurer` and implement the correct methods).

Comment: @M.Deinum removing AsyncConfigurer from CountyScraper did it. Thank You. You can write it in the answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess there are a couple of things not completely right in your code.

1. Your component implements `AsyncConfigurer`
2. You don't have `@EnableScheduling`

Your `CountyScraper` implements the `AsyncConfigurer` interface. Leading to 2 possible problems. The first is configuring async processing with the defaults and usage of interface based proxies instead of class based proxies. Hence eliminating the `@Async`. Although the latter doesn't seem to be the case, one might never know.

The `AsyncConfigurer` should actually be implemented by your `ExecutorConfig`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class ExecutorConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        return taskExecutor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new TaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        return taskExecutor;
    }
}
```

This will configure the default `Executor` used for async processing. Instead of a `ConcurrentTaskExecutor` I used the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` instead. The latter allows a bit more configuration and will cleanup the threads nicely when Spring Boot shutsdown.

**TIP:** If you are using Spring Boot 2.1 you can actually ditch the configuration of the `TaskExecutor` and replace it with configuration only.

Now you can use a simple `@Async` instead of naming the executor explicitly (which will now fail because it is named differently).

```
spring.task.execution.pool.core-size=10 # Default is 8
```

Your configuration then becomes

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class ExecutorConfig {}
```